# The number of circles that will fit inside the area of larger circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, packing-problem

Let's say circle $\omega_1$ has a diameter $X$. Let $X>Y$; $Y\in \mathbf{R}^{+}$. How many circles with diameter $Y$  will fit inside $\omega_1$?

Is there a formula for this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing; specifically, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle

Comment: You can assume $Y=1$ without loss of generality.

Comment: Given that many circle packing methods are conjectured (but not proven) optimal, the answer to your question "is there a formula for this" would be no.

Comment: you can $\frac{(x-x\%y)}{y}$ with the area.

Answer (score -2):

$${{\pi {X^2}} \over {\pi {Y^2}}}$$

=$${{{X^2}} \over {{Y^2}}}$$

Comment: This answer would be better if you added some explanation about why computing these quantities is useful.

Comment: area is a space, when you calculate a circle's area you calculate it's space contained by circumference. how many circles(diameter:-Y) can be drawn within the large circle(diameter:- X) mean the number of area included by the circle( diameter:-Y) into the large circle(diameter:-X)thank you. if you do not satisfy with my answer, please comment blow and say why?

Comment: This only gives an upper bound for the number of circles of diameter $Y$ which fit into a circle of diameter $X$. However, that upper bound is not attainable (unless $X = Y$). For instance, try packing $4$ circles of diameter $1$ into a larger circle of diameter $2$. You will see that it is not possible.